# Datetime com parâmetros desconhecidos

Tags: php, data, datetime

Estou integrando um programa com o Contaazul e um dos parâmetros é a data.
O Formato de data deles é este: "2020-01-08T16:28:59.966Z"

Para pegar no PHP essa data algumas partes é tranquilo, todavia alguém sabe o que é esse "T" e esse ".966Z" após o horário? Que formato de data e horário é esse?

O que são esses valores e como obter eles através do PHP?
Não localizei nada na documentação deles.

Comment: O formato de data está no padrão americano, onde `ANO/MÊS/DIA` ou `yyyy/mm/dd`. O `T` significa **TIME** (Tempo). o `.966` seriam os milissegundos

Comment: Funcionou Jakson. Obrigado!

Comment: Que isso, de nada meu amigo :)

Comment: Jakson, a API retornou: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX, esse SSSX são os millisegundos?

Comment: Consegue me passar o link da documentação pra que eu possa dar uma olhada?

Comment: @JaksonFischer Na verdade o formato americano é "mês/dia/ano". Esse formato da pergunta é definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e é "ano-mês-dia" (com hífen em vez de barras).

Comment: @hkotsubo, de fato, me confundi na hora da informação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse formato é definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Segundo esta norma, usa-se a letra "T" maiúscula para separar os campos de data e horário. Então temos "ano-mês-dia", seguido da letra "T", seguido de "hora:minuto:segundo".

Os segundos podem ter as frações (usando o ponto como o separador decimal), que no seu caso são 966 milissegundos.

Já o "Z" indica que esta data e hora [está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)).

Em PHP você pode usar um [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), que já reconhece esse formato por padrão:

```
$d = new DateTime('2020-01-08T16:28:59.966Z');

// mostrar a data em outro formato
echo $d->format('d/m/Y H:i:s.u e'); // 08/01/2020 16:28:59.966000 Z
```

---

Quanto ao [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429890/datetime-com-par%C3%A2metros-desconhecidos/429903#comment832953_429890) sobre o formato ser "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", *provavelmente* o "X" refere-se ao [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), que é a diferença com relação ao UTC. No seu exemplo, o "Z" refere-se ao próprio UTC, o que é o mesmo que dizer que o *offset* é zero. Você pode ver mais informações sobre *offsets* na [wiki da tag timezone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Obrigado hkotsubo!

Comment: Como fazer o caminho inverso? Tenho que inserir a letra T e Z manualmente? Por exemplo `echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');`

Comment: @GhoulSlasher Depende, no PHP 8 você pode usar `format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sp')`, mas em versões anteriores o "p" não é suportado, então tem que colocar o Z manualmente: `format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z')` (mas vc tem que ter certeza que a data está em UTC): https://stackoverflow.com/q/17390784

Comment: Está neste formato `1985-04-20T16:30:05.000Z`, o mais incrível disso tudo é que é um campo de data de nascimento de uma api que estou consumindo, fico me perguntando para que é essa hora. Estou usando php 7.2, mas consegui inserido o Z e T manualmente mesmo, pela função `format()`.